# ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Canada/East-Saskatchewan"

Tags: database, postgresql, timezone, database-restore

I'm importing a database which is working with psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.10. for my local database v.9.6.5.

This is the problematic part:

```
COPY timezone (id, name, windowsname, tzindex) FROM stdin;
...
315     Canada/East-Saskatchewan        \N      \N
...
```

This is the error I'm getting:

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 9024; 0 48454 TABLE DATA timezone skysms
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "timezone": ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Canada/East-Saskatchewan"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SET local timezone to 'Canada/East-Saskatchewan'"
PL/pgSQL function display_in_other_tz(timestamp with time zone,text,text) line 7 at EXECUTE statement
COPY timezone, line 315: "315   Canada/East-Saskatchewan        \N      \N"`

Comment: do you see it between `select * from pg_timezone_names where name like 'Canada%';`?..

Comment: No, only ```Canada/Saskatchewan```.

Comment: as far s `FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names(OUT name text, OUT abbrev text, OUT utc_offset interval, OUT is_dst boolean)` you need a help of smbd close to postgres source. I would assume absence of `EastSaskatchewan` is a bug...

Comment: It exists in the original server. I'm not sure how it got there (or why it's not in my local DB).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The zone `Canada/East-Saskatchewan` used to be a valid time zone identifier.  It was a link/alias for the `America/Regina` time zone.  However, it was *removed* from the tz database in the last version (2017c).  You can see the commit [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/d5054b62469ef1b1b0cea3192f6cc814ade989d9).

[The 2017c release announcement](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2017-October/000047.html) states:

> Remove Canada/East-Saskatchewan from the 'backward' file, as it exceeded the 14-character limit and was an unused misnomer anyway.

So, while *normally* time zone identifiers are not removed in this manner, for this particular one it was deemed necessary due to its length.

You can safely update any entry of `Canada/East-Saskatchewan` to the prefered locality-based form of the zone: `America/Regina`.